# How to extract specific text from a field in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following sample of data where I want to extract a specific text from the Order description field.

For example:
There are 3 records of sales with the same Order ID and Invoice ID, however, the Order Amount does not reflect the true total for each of these sales records.

Is there a way for me to **extract the cost of items out from Order Description column in Excel? Please do share the f**ormulas if there is any!

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use `FILTERXML`:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '$')]"),1)
```

If you don't have Excel O365, you could strip off the `INDEX()`. I have it in there to take the first amount from the resulting array of amounts to prevent spilling it.

Comment: Instead of using `INDEX` in `O365` you could merely prefix the formula with `@` to return the first element in the array:  `=@FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '$')]")`

Comment: That's true and pretty cool @RonRosenfeld. Good tip

Answer (score 2):

**If all your data follows same structure** (that means the price starts with `$` and it ends with `,` ) you can do it like this:

```
=MID(A1;SEARCH("$";A1);SEARCH(", ";A1)-SEARCH("$";A1))
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Wrap everything inside a VALUE function, so the output will be a number.

Comment: Very nicely thought of. Much easier. Also, if the comma does not yet exists like in `C5`, then you can use `=--MID(A1,FIND("$",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1&",")-FIND("$",A1)-1)`

Comment: thank you! could you explain a little on the logic behind your formula pls? @JvdV